# check two column values of two csv files and if match found write to a another csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, match

i have two csv files named 1.csv and 2.csv with 1.csv of 50 lines and 2.csv of 75 lines. now i am trying to findout if username and feature is present in both files then write to a new file.

my code so far is :

```
with open('1.csv') as a:
    c=pd.read_csv(a)
    with open('2.csv') as b:
        d=pd.read_csv(b)
        if (c['User'] == d['User'] and c['Feature'] == d['Feature'] and c['ipaddress'] == d['ipaddress']):
         c.to_csv('3.csv')
```

but with this code i am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/main.py", line 181, in <module>
    if (c['User'] == d['User'] and c['Feature'] == d['Feature'] and c['ipaddress'] == d['ipaddress']):
  File "path\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1190, in wrapper
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
1.csv :
name feature start_date 
aaaa  apple  2018-02-10 
bbbb  mango  2018-03-11 
cccc  orange 2018-04-12 
dddd  guava  2018-05-13 

2.csv : 

name feature  end_date
aaaa  apple   2018-02-13
bbbb  mango   2018-03-16
cccc  orange  2018-04-15
dddd  guava   2018-05-18
eeee  Avocado 2018-06-14
ffff  Banana  2018-07-13
gggg  Bilberry 2018-08-09

Expected output 3.csv

name feature start_date end_date   difference
aaaa  apple  2018-02-10 2018-02-13 3days.
bbbb  mango  2018-03-11 2018-03-16 5days.
cccc  orange 2018-04-12 2018-04-15 3days.
dddd  guava  2018-05-13 2018-05-18 5days.
```

Comment: Define what you mean by "match" and show an example please

Comment: Thanks, i have edited my question. please check

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this in few lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Uncomment to read from file and comment out a, b vars from pd.DataFrame
#a = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
#b = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
a = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd'],
                  'feature': ['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'guava'],
                  'start_date': ['2018-02-10','2018-03-11','2018-04-12','2018-05-13',]})

b = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'gggg'],
                  'feature': ['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'guava', 'Avocado', 'Banana','Bilberry',],
                  'end_date': ['2018-02-13','2018-03-16','2018-04-15','2018-05-18','2018-06-14','2018-07-13','2018-08-09']})

# replace to on=['name', 'feature', 'ipaddress'] if needed.
# In example you don't have 'ipaddress', but in your code you have it
c = pd.merge(a, b, how='inner', on=['name', 'feature'])
c['difference'] = pd.to_datetime(c['end_date']) - pd.to_datetime(c['start_date'])
print(c)
#Uncomment to save to file
#c.to_csv('3.csv')
```

Check variables. It completely same as in your example.

```
print(a)

   name feature  start_date
0  aaaa   apple  2018-02-10
1  bbbb   mango  2018-03-11
2  cccc  orange  2018-04-12
3  dddd   guava  2018-05-13

print(b)

   name   feature    end_date
0  aaaa     apple  2018-02-13
1  bbbb     mango  2018-03-16
2  cccc    orange  2018-04-15
3  dddd     guava  2018-05-18
4  eeee   Avocado  2018-06-14
5  ffff    Banana  2018-07-13
6  gggg  Bilberry  2018-08-09

print(c)

   name feature  start_date    end_date difference
0  aaaa   apple  2018-02-10  2018-02-13     3 days
1  bbbb   mango  2018-03-11  2018-03-16     5 days
2  cccc  orange  2018-04-12  2018-04-15     3 days
3  dddd   guava  2018-05-13  2018-05-18     5 days
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried your code but its giving 900 combinations possible, that is it is joining 75 lines of 2.csv  to each single lines of 1.csv that is 50 lines.

Comment: did you add "on=['name', 'feature']"?   It works perfectly well for example in your question

Comment: you didn't include ipaddress in your example.
replace on=['name', 'feature'] to on=['name', 'feature', 'ipaddress'] and you good

Comment: thanks, but still i am getting the same error can you make a snippet?

Comment: I've edited my answer, now check variables. It's 100% as in your example. It works.

Comment: By the way, which version of Python and pandas do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Use merge.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = ['name','feature'],how = 'left')
```

Then you can perform the subtraction for dates, depending on the data type of the timestamp columns.

Comment: i tried that but since i have different number of lines on both files, i cannot use it. if i use it then for a single row in 1.csv i will have 7 entries in the output file.

Comment: You must have been missing ````how = 'left'````. With that argument there is no way for the number of resulting rows to exceed the number of rows in df1.